# Android emulator in android studio show upside down ui. how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

[image: here's what the emulator look like]

After update to android studio hedgehod when I start the emulator it show ui like this. I've tried to delete and create it again but it still the same.

Comment: Would not call that upside down. What is the problem?

Comment: you can see in the picture

Comment: I see no problem. Please enjoy this Android 15 feature ;-).

Comment: look at the image agian why you don't see the problem

Comment: can't you see the navigator button stay at the top?

Comment: If i cant see then you cant read as i mentioned it a feature.

Comment: how is it a feature?

Comment: Can you tell me how to turn off this feature thing? cuz this look more like a bug to me

Comment: Sorry, i have no hedgehod and Android 15 ;-). Settings?

Comment: what setting do you want me to show?